# Combine two mysql queries with two different order by statements

Tags: mysql

I want to combine these two queries.

```
   SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE status='pending' and adr='' order by id desc limit 0,1;

   SELECT * FROM table1 where status='pending' and adr='new' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I want a pony and free pizza.  Did you have a *question*?  You could concatenate the results from these queries using a `UNION ALL` set operator, Reference [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html)  You'd need to wrap each query in parens to get the ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses honored with each query.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a UNION ALL set operator to concatenate the results of the two queries

```
( SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE status='pending' AND adr='' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 )
UNION ALL
( SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE status='pending' AND adr='new' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 )
```

Reference: [**UNION ALL**  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html)